# Work done in adiabatic process irreversible and reversible

Tags: thermodynamics, work, reversibility, adiabatic

Work done for adiabatic reversible process is $(P1V1 - P2V2)/(γ-1)$ but this is also the work done for adiabatic irreversible process. How?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Why do you say that the work done in an adiabatic process is irreversible?

Comment: This is the work done for a process that is *both* adiabatic *and* reversible.

Comment: I changed the question. Can you please answer it now?

Comment: As Chestermiller and I have both pointed out, the quantity of work you quote is for a REVERSIBLE adiabatic expansion of an ideal gas. What is your problem with this?

Answer (score 1):

You quote the case of *reversible* adiabatic expansion, where the gas (in an insulated cylinder of low heat capacity) expands slowly, pushing a piston and doing the amount of work that you quoted.

An extreme example of an *irreversible* adiabatic process is called *Joule expansion*. An insulated vessel is partitioned into two chambers. One has a gas in it, the other a vacuum. The partition breaks, so that the gas expands into a vacuum. We have *irreversible* adiabatic expansion, and the gas does no work at all!

A less extreme example of irreversible adiabatic expansion would be when the gas expands very rapidly. If the piston's speed is not negligible compared with the rms speed of the gas molecules, the gas pressure next to the piston will be less than that in the bulk of the gas, so the work done will be less than in the reversible case.

Comment: Please change the answer as i changed the question

Comment: My answer above still stands. I don't want to seem rude, but you don't seem to have read it. I re-iterate: $\frac{p_1 V_1-p_2 V_2}{\gamma -1}$ is the work done by an ideal gas expanding reversibly. The work done when it expands $irreversibly$ between the same two states is less.

Comment: I should have said "between the same two volumes" rather than "between the same two states".